# Drop digits from an integer

Tags: java

Here's a homework problem I came across:

> Input an integer, greater than or equal to 0. Multiply it by 5, add 6 to the product, multiply by 4, add 9 and multiply by 5. Then, remove the last two digits of the final number and subtract 1. Output the answer. Call your Java class Computations.

I solved it by converting the input to string, slice it and convert it back to an integer. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Computations {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean legal = false;
        int integer = -1;

        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
        do {
            if (input.hasNextInt() && input.nextInt()>=0) {
                legal = true;
                integer = input.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Illegal input!");
            }
        } while (!legal);
        System.out.println(((((integer * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5)/100-1);
    }
}
```

Here I'm putting everything together, and does doing so compromise readability and make it hard to understand?

Comment: Hint: a division by `10` removes the last digit from an `int`. The rest should be obvious.

Comment: You should maybe ask this as two questions - one about your existing+working Java implementation (maybe on [CodeReview](https://www.codereview.stackexchange.com)), the other about a Haskell implementation (including your own attempt to implement it).

Comment: why is it tagged haskell?

Comment: @prayagupd I asked how to do it haskell, then I decided to ask it in a separate post but forgot to remove the tag.

Comment: Just divide by 10, why make it complicated. With little more research from the OP, he could figured that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is actually **just outputting the input** - as long as the input is between 0 and 21,474,834.

---

The given equation gives the same value as is input. The first few operations give us:

```
5 * (4 * (5x + 6) + 9)
=   20 * (5x + 6) + 45
=       100x + 165
```

"Removing the last two digits" is equivalent to dividing by 100 and truncating the decimal part (we can use `floor` as the input is non-negative), which gives:

```
floor((100x + 165) / 100) = floor(x + 1.65) = x + 1
```

Subtracting 1 then just gives `x`, the input.

---

This won't necessarily give the same input if the computation would **overflow**. An `int` in Java is a signed 32 bit integer, so the largest value we can store is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 = 2,147,483,647. If the largest intermediate value in the equation goes over this, we won't get the right answer:

```
100x + 165 <= 2147483647
```

Gives the maximum `x` for which this approach will give the same value as an approach which performs each operation, as 21,474,834.

---

All this said, your (updated) code is a good solution and is perfectly readable. You should consider introducing error checks (your quote says the input must be `>=0`, this is worth enforcing).

Adding a comment explaining that "an integer division by 100 is used to trim the last two digits" is also probably a good idea, as another developer reading your code later may assume you've made a mistake (didn't realise it would truncate). Whenever you rely on unusual behaviour, **document it**.

Comment: By "unusual behavior", you mean using the divisor as a truncator?

Comment: What if I want to remove digits at arbitrary positions? For example, remove the first, third and sixth digits?

Comment: By the way, I don't think "floor" is necesarry, because we are dealing with integers?

Comment: @ChristianTemple "*What if I want to remove digits at arbitrary positions?*" - again, please refrain from asking new question in comments.

Comment: @Turing85 I've added a question within my post as well, thanks.

Comment: @ChristianTemple Yep, unusual behaviour is using division to truncate a number. It's just because it could be mistaken for intending a non-truncating division (using floating point numbers etc). Removing arbitrary digits, it's probably simplest at that point to just convert it to a string. `floor` is just representing the mathematical floor (to properly represent integer division), as I was talking in "maths domain" rather than "programming domain" at the time.

Comment: @ChristianTemple [Please do not ask multiple questions per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: @Turing85 But I think my question is closely related though?

Comment: @ChristianTemple you keep changing/extending your question and thus practically invalidate all answers, if those are not edited. What is worse is that a user does not get notified, if a question s/he has answered, got edited, thus s/he could receive downvotes (for example) and would not necessarily know why. Just look at the answer to this question: hnefatl edited his answer just under one minute ago, all other answers are at least 27 minutes old.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can use

```
int i = (integer/100)-1;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Then, remove the last two digits of the final number and subtract 1.

Why not just divide by `100` and then subtract `1`.

```
iTotal = (((iTotal * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5;
iTotal = (iTotal / 100) - 1;
```

Also, keeping variable name as `integer` is not at all good practice.

Comment: "keeping variable name as integer is not at all good practice", that's interesting. Can you explain it for me?

Comment: @ChristianTemple what explanation ?? do you know, Java has class with name `Integer`. Also, as per naming convention `integer` name not at all good practice. Please read to know, what is best practice http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Why it not a good practice? I've read the link but still don't see the reason why not.

Comment: @ChristianTemple ok, tell me what is good reason for naming it as `integer` knowing there is already a class with same name in java. Now, imagine, you have encounter such code `integer/100`, so what would you think when you at first instance.

Comment: that makes it obvious that "integer" is an integer

Comment: @ChristianTemple hahaha.. so.. according to you `String` variable name can be `string` ?? What is obvious for you that doesn't make the good practice. Just open any existing API and see the coding standard

Comment: how about naming it as "input"?

Comment: @ChristianTemple That is kind of ok, but still not acceptable. If you read the link, which I mentioned (although that link is old)

Comment: @Ravi laughing over a beginner's mistake made by a beginner is very motivating...

Comment: @Turing85 Did you get my facial expression as well. That was smile. Did I teased him ??? Also, when you say you are beginner, then you need to understand as  beginner. Don't put your logic there

Answer (score 1):

you can try this line in your code:

```
int digit = (integer/100)-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could have the number divided by 100 and then truncate it afterward.
Something like:

```
removing_last_2 = (int) integer/100;
```

Or if you can guarantee that the number is always positive:

```
removing_last_2 = Math.floor(integer/100);
```

Comment: As `integer` is an `int` already, you don't need the `(int)` cast and using `Math.floor` will give a compilation error (its arguments must be `float` or `double`, you're passing it an `int`). The existing "truncate" behaviour of `/` is all you need.

Comment: Also following the java coding conventions, you should use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for variable names.

Comment: My bad, I thought that the division by 100 would cause it to transform into a float.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework problem, I will try to point you in the right direction.

You can solve this with arithmetics without converting it to a String. I would recommend using the [Remainder Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html): `%`

Example:

```
124 % 4
```

Returns:

```
0
```

But:

```
124 % 3
```

Returns:

```
1
```

Take the remainder and remove it from your total to get the desired output.

As for elegance, there is not a universal standard. The idea is to make your code as simple AND readable as possible. Extracting logic into private methods is a good start.

As for Haskell, I do not know it. You will have to do some web searching.

Comment: How is the remainder able to help?

Comment: Since the OP has posted his solution, `integer % 100` will return the value he needs to remove. Ex: `124 % 100` returns 24.

Comment: @TEK292 you misunderstood the question. The last two digits should be removed, i.e. `124` -> `1`

Comment: So, does putting everything together as what I'm doing in my new solution compromise readability? "Extracting logic into private methods", this doesn't  apply to small programs like this, I think?

Comment: @Turing85 you are correct. apologies. @ Christian in my opinion yes. But my opinion is not the law. Extracting logic into private methods can apply to any class regardless of size. Given your current solution, you could move the arithmetic logic to a private method.