# Removing digits from an integer

Tags: haskell

Here's a homework problem I came across:

> Input an integer, greater than or equal to 0. Multiply it by 5, add 6 to the product, multiply by 4, add 9 and multiply by 5. Then, remove the last two digits of the final number and subtract 1. Output the answer.

Here's my code:

```
1  main = do
2      putStrLn "enter a non-negative integer: "
3      input <- getLine
4      let i = (read input :: Int)
5      print ((((i * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5)/100-1
```

Here, I'm trying to truncate the last two digits by dividing it by 100, since this works in other languages. 
However, it gives me this error and I'm not sure what it means:

```
$ runhaskell Computations.hs

Computations.hs:5:5: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional (IO ())) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the first argument of ‘(-)’, namely
        ‘print ((((x * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) / 100’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print ((((x * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) / 100 - 1
      In the expression:
        do { putStrLn "enter a non-negative integer: ";
             input1 <- getLine;
             let x = (read input1 :: Int);
             print ((((x * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) / 100 - 1 }

Computations.hs:5:5: error:
    • No instance for (Num (IO ())) arising from a use of ‘-’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print ((((x * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) / 100 - 1
      In the expression:
        do { putStrLn "enter a non-negative integer: ";
             input1 <- getLine;
             let x = (read input1 :: Int);
             print ((((x * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) / 100 - 1 }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { putStrLn "enter a non-negative integer: ";
                   input1 <- getLine;
                   let x = ...;
                   .... }
```

So, can anyone explain what the error means?

Are there any other solutions better than trucating by a divisor?

How can I remove digits at arbitrary positions? For example, remove the first, second and sixth digits from an integer?

ps: input and output should match if done correctly.

Update: I've changed "/" to "div" and it gives me this:

```
Computations.hs:5:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
                                    -> Integer -> Integer’
                  with actual type ‘Int’
    • The function ‘(((i * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5’
      is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘Int’ has none
      In the first argument of ‘(-)’, namely
        ‘((((i * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) div 100’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(((((i * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) div 100 - 1)’
```

This part is strange: "The function ‘(((i * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5’ is applied to two arguments", why does haskell interpret it as a function?

Comment: Use `div`, not `/`.

Comment: Integer division is `div`, not `/`.

Comment: @chepner, if you leave out the stated pre-condition, the correct division operation will be `quot`, not `div`.

Comment: You have to put `div` in backquotes if you want to use it like an operator.

Comment: In case anyone noticed that blip: I closed as dup then saw the edit.  It's basically a typo now but answerable.

Comment: Replace `x/y` by ```x `div` y``` or `div x y`, but not `x div y`.

Comment: I was in the process of answering his follow-up questions when this was closed as dupe. I'm not certain it's actually a duplicate of that, at least not insofar as anyone searching "removing digits from an integer" could be reasonably helped by the target.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I tend to think of `div` as a special-purpose function. The best default is probably "Euclidean" division, which it's sadly missing from the `Prelude`. Therefore `quot`, which is less distant from machine division, should be preferred.

Comment: FYI, you can use the following (imo easier to follow) code: `transform = (subtract 1) . (\`quot\` 100) . (*5) . (+9) . (*4) . (+6) . (*5)`, although the answer to "Are there any other solutions better than trucating by a divisor?" is already given in my [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194477/drop-digits-from-an-integer/48194868#48194868), so probably doesn't need repeating here.

Comment: @hnefatl nice one

Comment: @dfeuer Google tells me “Euclidean division” is division that produces a result and a remainder. That exists in the Prelude as divMod, so I’m not sure what you’re trying to say.

Comment: @HTNW, I'm referring specifically to the version that ensures `0 <= mod x y < y` along with the more obvious `y * div x y + mod x y = x`.

Comment: @dfeuer That *is* how mod works. mod’s result has the same sign as the divisor, which fits your inequality for positive divisors.

Comment: @HTNW, yes, but not for negative divisors! It also happens that the way the `Prelude` does it takes one more comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can anyone explain what the error means?**

The precedence in your first line is off - infix functions (like `/`) usually have a higher precedence than normal ones, so `print (...) / 100` is equivalent to `(print ...) / 100`, which is obviously problematic. You can wrap everything in brackets, or use the `$` function:

```
print $ ((((i * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) / 100 - 1
```

Now as you've constrained `i` to be an `Int`, this will still give an error: `/` is only defined for instances of the `Fractional` typeclass, and `Int` isn't. You want integer division, `div` or `quot`, which operates only on `Integral`s (of which `Int` is an instance) and perform truncation as you want:

```
print $ ((((i * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) `div` 100 - 1
```

Note the backticks (`), which allow a normal function to be used infix. You could write this as:

```
print $ (div ((((i * 5) + 6) * 4 + 9) * 5) 100) - 1
```

But then the brackets are making things really hard to read.

---

**Are there any other solutions better than truncating by a divisor?**

In general probably not, but [as mentioned on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194477/drop-digits-from-an-integer), this particular equation will always give you the **same result as your input**, so you can just write:

```
main = getLine >>= print
```

---

**How can I remove digits at arbitrary positions?**

Converting to a string and removing characters is likely your best bet. Something like the following will work, although it's arguably a bit dense:

```
removeDigits :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
removeDigits indices x = read . reverse . filterIndices indices . reverse . show $ x

filterIndices :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
filterIndices inds elems = map snd . filter ((`notElem` inds) . fst) . zip [1..] $ elems
```

Note this treats the last digit as the "1st" digit - it's a bit more natural to refer to digits with.

---

An (in my opinion) easier to read representation of your existing code is:

```
transform = (subtract 1) . (`quot` 100) . (*5) . (+9) . (*4) . (+6) . (*5)
```

With this way of writing it, composition overrides the arithmetic precedence laws, letting us write it how it's read ("times 5, add 6, times 4, ..."). We have to use `subtract 1`, as `-1` is interpreted as the literal value `-1`, not as a unary function.

Answer (score 3):

Removing digits at arbitrary positions is an interesting problem. This is probably easiest to do by converting to string and performing string manipulation, then reading back as an Int. Since `Int` implements both `Show` and `Read`, you can do:

```
type Digit = Int

removeDigits :: [Digit] -> Int -> Int
removeDigits digits = read . go 1 . show
  where
  go _ []     = []
  go i (c:cs) | i `elem` digits = go cs (i+1)
              | otherwise       = c : go cs (i+1)
-- N.B. I chose 1-indexing here instead of 0-indexing because of your word choice
-- "remove the first, second, and sixth digits" maps naturally to [1, 2, 6],
-- though programmers may find that off-putting. YMMV.
```

`removeDigits` here could be re-written as

```
read [c | (i, c) <- zip [1..] (show n), i `notElem` digits]
```

Comment: can you take a look at my last question posted at the end? thanks.

Comment: @ChristianTemple It's because `div` isn't an infix function, so the compiler gets confused by the precedence. Using `\`div\`` as Chepner commented will fix this. However, as you were told on your previous question, you should **post new questions**, rather than edit your existing one.